# Assumption of almost supermartingagles convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, martingales

My question is about the assumption of the following result, which is due to Robbins and Siegmund.

> Suppose that $(\varOmega,\mathscr{F},P)$ is a probability space.
>   Let $(\mathscr{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a filtration in $\mathscr{F}$.
>   For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $X_n\colon\varOmega\to\left[0,{+}\infty\right[$ be a random variable
>   which is $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable, and let $Y_n\colon\varOmega\to\left[0,{+}\infty\right[$
>   be a random variable. Suppose that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}Y_n<{+}\infty$ $P$-a.s. and that
>   $$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\quad\mathbb{E}\big(X_{n+1}~|~\mathscr{F}_n\big)\leq X_n+Y_n\quad \text{$P$-a.s.}
> $$
>   Then $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges almost surely.

The main idea is to define
$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\quad Z_n=X_n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}Y_k
$$
and show that $(Z_n,\mathscr{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a supermartingale. This leads to the following questions:

1. Do we have to assume that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are integrable? Otherwise the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}\big(X_{n+1}~|~\mathscr{F}_n\big)$ does not make sense.
2. Similarly, do we have to assume that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are integrable so that $\mathbb{E}\big(Z_{n}~|~\mathscr{F}_n\big)$ is well defined? I could not see how one can infer from the almost sure summability of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}Y_n$ that $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are integrable.

Robbins and Siegmund did not mention these assumptions in their original work, but it seems to me that these assumptions are important.

Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a non-negative random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$, it is still possible to define the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]$ when $X$ has infinite expectation:

Recall that the existence of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]$ in the usual situation where $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$ is guaranteed by the Radon-Nikodym theorem. The standard version of this theorem assumes that both of the measures in question are $\sigma$-finite, but there is actually an extension to the case where $\nu$ is a positive measure (but not necessarily $\sigma$-finite), $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, and $\nu\ll\mu$, provided that one is willing to allow the Radon-Nikodym derivative to take the value $\infty$. This extension is generally relegated to the exercises of measure theory textbooks (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240132/extension-of-radon-nikodym-theorem) for some references), but is precisely what is needed to define the conditional expectation in the situation where $X$ is non-negative but has infinite expectation.

Comment: But here we are not sure whether the random variable $Z_n$ is positive or not. Is it necessary to assume that both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are integrable in the above theorem?

Comment: Actually I think the version in Folland's exercises does not even assume that $\nu$ is positive, so presumably that is what is being used for the $Z_n$. I think you have to be a bit more careful with $\pm\infty$, and to be honest I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to assume that $X_n$ or $Y_n$ is integrable.  It's not hard to check that if the basic inequality is satisfied, then so is the same inequality with $X_n$ and $Y_n$ replace by $\min(X_n,c)$, $\min(Y_n,c)$ (respectively) for each constant $c>0$. The supermartingale argument then shows that $\lim_n\min(X_n,c)$ exists a.s. for each $c>0$, which implies that $\lim_nX_n$ exists, a.s., as well.

Comment: Do you have a reference (book/article) that I could refer to?

Comment: @JohnDawkins what if $X_k$ verifies $$E[X_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_k] \leq X_k+Y_k-W_k$$ where $W_k$ is an adapted, positive processes? We still have convergence on $\{\sum_k Y_k <\infty\}$

Comment: @Kurt.W.X: Because $W_k\ge 0$  you have $E[X_{k+1}|\mathcal F_k]\le X_k+Y_k$, so the present discussion applies.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: in this case we also have $\sum_k W_k<\infty $ a.s on $\{\sum_{k}Y_k<\infty\}$ that's why I asked if there is an alternative way